# Error: Could not find or load main class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DocsConnectionPropsHelper

Tags: java, jdbc

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sv0P.png)
I am getting an error when I am running this code.

I came to know there is no com.mysql.jdbc.DocsConnectionPropsHelper class in Connector/J version 8.0.28. But this class does exist in Connector/J 5.1.x.

So why I am getting this error when I am using Connector j 8.3.0 version.

I want to know the solution this this problem and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).